# jQuery show div on hover - hide div on mouseout

Tags: jquery, css

I have an anchor tag, which when hovered, I want a certain div ("mark") to show up. The div is NOT inside the anchor tag.

The HTML is as follows:

```
       <a href="#" class="mark"></a>
          <div class="icontent">
                <p>
                lorem ipsum dolor sit amet......
                 </p>
           </div>
```

When mouse is hovered on ".mark", ".icontent" should show up. When mouse is out, ".icontent" should hide again. Is it also possible to add a 1 second transition to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="mark">hover anchor</a>
<div class="icontent">
  <p>
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet......
  </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function(){
  var del = 200;
  $('.icontent').hide().prev('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.icontent').stop('fx', true).slideToggle(del);
  });
})();
```

Example
http://jsbin.com/evehat/1/edit

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: (function(){
  var del = 200;
  $('.info').hide().prev('.question-mark').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.info').stop('fx', true).slideToggle(del);
  });
})(); works

Answer (score 5):

hover() will work nicely here:

```
$('.mark').hover(function() {$('.icontent').show(1000)}, function() {$('.icontent').hide(1000)});
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Works for me, however there's nothing on that page with class 'mark' or 'icontent'.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".mark").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(".icontent").stop().show(1000);
    },

    mouseout: function() {
        $(".icontent").stop().hide(1000);
    }
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pz2Rw/9/)

Comment: if multiply hovering occure than action repeated unnessecerely, here stop needed on out

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".mark").hover(function () {
   if (!$(".icontent").is(":animated")) {
      $(".icontent").show('slow');
   }
}, function () {
   $(".icontent").stop().hide('slow');
});​
```

You could also use `mouseover` and `mouseout` separately.  The `:animated` and `.stop` additions are done to prevent wise guys from moving their mouse over and o ut of the anchor repeatedly.

Comment: @dmi3y thanks, wrong question.  But now I lost the jQuery example I meant to link to!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mark').hover(function()      {$('.icontent')).fadeIn(1000)},
function(){$('.icontent').fadeOut(1000)});
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mark").mouseover(function() {
    $('.icontent').fadeIn(1000);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.icontent').fadeOut(1000);
});
```